# Broken CSV exports

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export, csv, contactbuilder, data-synchronization

I've exported several csvs to ftp from synchronized data extension and it appears that they are broken (ie. there are blank rows or certain rows that bleed into the next row.

Wondering if this is a known issue, or rather an issue with my MS excel software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is an issue with text delimeters of microsoft office?

When you import .csv Files where in some columns there could be values that inherit delimeters like " in odd-times, it may be that excel missinterprets this as an open text qualifier. Then this cell with inherit MUCH information until the next " appears with a following real delimeter like ;.

Maybe this could be your problem.

Comment: Yep - you're right, I think.  Excel is misinterpreting text fields that contain delimiters.  \

Comment: Best bet is to utilize txt files with unusual delimiters like pipe ( | ) or sometimes I even use tilde ( ~ ) delimiters.  This helps remove potential issues with the delimiter being inside one of the fields.